# How to go about accessing MasterPage body from another page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've got a log-in page with a drop down list, which you can pick a background color for the website. But I'm having trouble linking the masterpage's body with the selected value on the drop down list.

```
<body style="overflow: auto;" runat="server" id="bodyMasterPage">
```

Here's the opening tag of my MasterPage body, and here's the dropdownlist I've got.

```
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblColor" ClientIDMode="Static" AssociatedControlID="ddlColor" class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlColor" ClientIDMode="Static" aria-describedby="lbColor" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle" class="btn dropdown-toggle DropDownListHint-datastyle">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Бял" Value="White" Selected="True" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Зелен" Value="Green" />
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Master.FindControl Method

```
var body = Master.FindControl("bodyMasterPage");
```